# Em qual data está o StackOverflow?

Tags: suporte, layout

Ao acessar o meu perfil, me deparei com a seguinte situação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não sei como o site lida com as datas, mas não sei dizer se é dia 13 ou 14, isso pela marcação no jQuery UI (Datepicker).

Porém, minha dúvida não é realmente sobre isso, e sim na data (e hora) real que foi tirado.

Como pode ser visto na imagem, a data é 12/10/2016 às 21:17. Porém, pelo calendário mostra que eu já acessei o dia 12/10 e o dia 13/10 ou que estamos no dia 13/10, não entendi direito.

Eu apenas gostaria de entender qual é a data correta ou se possui algo errado realmente.

Comment: Relacionados: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Utc

Comment: @Math Vou ler as perguntas. Achei que já tivesse algo relacionado, mas não sabia qual termo utilizar nas pesquisas. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Tem algumas, ficou difícil escolher uma só e para dificultar ainda mais eu tô acessando pelo cel

Comment: Acho que esta é relacionada diretamente: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1229/101 e esta provavelmente duplicata, ainda que o foco ligeiramente diferente: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2354/101

Comment: @bigown Acho que as duas estão relacionadas e aceitaria as duas como duplicatas. Votei na primeira apenas pela data de criação da pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O horário do site é [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), o único que faria sentido para um site de acesso internacional. Então pelo horário brasileiro principal, se não estamos em horário de verão  (UTC-0300), 21:00 vira o dia. Em horário de verão (UTC-0200) obviamente isso ocorre às 22:00.

Se verificar os horários de todas postagens tem a diferença de fuso horário entre UTC e nosso horário.

Comment: Então, pelo calendário, o que está em verde por último (dia 13) é o atual? Sendo mais específico, o atual e que eu acessei, visto que o calendário em questão é o do meu acesso no site.

Comment: Sim. No exato momento deste comentário estamos no dia 13, que vai até às 21:00 (nosso horário). Inclusive é o horário que vira reputação, portanto é o horário que sempre espero chegar para começar notificar verdinho de novo :D

Comment: A parte de 21:00 eu já sabia, por questões de votos. O que me deixou confuso foi esse calendário (verde os dias acessados). Mas entendi como ele está se comportando, muito obrigado.

Comment: É a mesma coisa, começa contar votos de novo depois que capa às 21:00 porque virou o dia.

Comment: Sim, o que me confundiu foi o verde do calendário. A primeira impressão era que o calendário sugeria que a data atual seria dia 14, pois todas as outras datas estavam verdes. Mas já entendi, vlw

Comment: Não, a data atual é 13, mesmo que a primeira coisa que faça no site exatamente às 21:00 seja olhar o calendário já terá feito um acesso no dia 13, então ele já está verde.

Comment: Na verdade, nem é por causa de ser uma aplicação internacional. A verdadeira razão é que esse é o fuso horário do @JonSkeet. /s